# ssh via multiple interfaces eth0 wlan0 to internet

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to open multiple reverse ssh tunnels via different interfaces (on a raspberry pi with raspbian strech) for a fallback.

That said I do have problems to open outgoing ssh connections over different interfaces. Right now there is:

- eth0 as static IP (192.168.1.200)
- wlan0 via dhcp (192.168.178.100)

Binding ssh to IP-address is working for "eth0" but not for "wlan0":

- `ssh -b 192.168.1.200 user@externalip` is working
- `ssh -b 192.168.178.100 user@externalip` is **NOT** working

besides that, i can traceroute via both interfaces to internet:

- `ssh -b 192.168.1.200 user@externalip` is working

sudo traceroute -i wlan0 google.com

```
traceroute to google.com (172.217.21.14), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.178.1 (192.168.178.1)  12.528 ms  17.229 ms  21.757 ms
 2  192.0.0.1 (192.0.0.1)  26.576 ms  41.445 ms  47.408 ms ...
  ...
```

sudo traceroute -i eth0 google.com

```
traceroute to google.com (172.217.21.14), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  0.537 ms  0.404 ms  0.570 ms
  ...
```

Any idea how to make ssh over both interfaces work?

route -n:

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default only the first matching entry in the (main) routing table will be used to determine the route to the destination. Moreover, a packet that is not received on this matching entry will be discarded because of [`rp_filter`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=linux-4.14.y#n1124).

Your setup requires policy routing: the route must now depend not only on the destination, but also on the source, by storing multiples routes in multiple routing tables and selecting the adequate table, thus route, depending on the source. The previous statement stays true: the first matching route in the table will be chosen, but it might be chosen from (a) different(s) table(s).

So you first set additional routing tables (table values chosen "arbitrarily") to complement what wouldn't have worked only using the `main` table:

```
ip route add table 1921681    default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
ip route add table 192168178  default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlan0
```

Then the right source selector is used to choose the adequate table with [`ip rule`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iproute2/ip-rule.8.en.html). Here one new rule only would be enough, but for the sake of symmetry, both will be added, allowing more flexibility on the main routing table, eg when changing metrics (see later):

```
ip rule add from 192.168.0.0/22   lookup 1921681
ip rule add from 192.168.178.0/24 lookup 192168178
```

The rules are now:

```
# ip rule
0:  from all lookup local 
32764:  from 192.168.178.0/24 lookup 192168178 
32765:  from 192.168.0.0/22 lookup 1921681 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Consider entries `32764` et `32765` as exceptions to the entry `32766` looking up the usual `main` table.

That's it, now your previous commands will work as intended, both routes can work at the same time, when you state the source IP with option `-b`.

If you don't state the source IP, the system will not immediately match on the additional rules and routing tables, and will default to the choice made when using the main table: first matching route will win, thus selecting source `192.168.1.200` in your current setup.

To repeat it again, if you don't explictly state a source IP (as is usually the case), your main route will still select the *default* default route and the corresponding default source IP, then the rules `32764` and `32765` will ensure it stays working correctly whatever the case. You can thus play with the metrics to choose which route and IP takes precedence.

Example, to have `wlan0` be now prefered when not stating the source IP, increase the `202` metric of `eth0` to `1000` to have `wlan0`'s default route, thus IP be chosen first. Stating explicitly the source IP will still directly match on rules `32764` or `32765`. Previously established connections count as "stating the source IP", thus won't be disturbed.

```
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 metric 1000
ip route del default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 metric 202
```

Some additional notes:

- Don't try to remove all default routes in the `main` (usual) table, or your connections won't establish anymore if the application doesn't state the source IP ("`Network is unreachable`").
- More complex cases are possible, including having the same IP on two different networks, but this will require additional settings and probably help from netfilter and `iptables`.
- It's even possible to load-balance those routes by using [`iptables`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iptables/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#statistic) and [marks](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iptables/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#MARK) and use those marks as selector in `ip rule`, but it's more complex to have it working correctly in all cases especially when mixing connections where source IP is stated and where source IP is left to be chosen by the system, and also especially for UDP. It might then also require an awkward use of NAT and loosening [`rp_filter`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=linux-4.14.y#n1124).

Comment: Thank you for your answer - seems to solve the problem. Would these rules survive a reboot of the remote machine?

Comment: Of course not. Yuu have to integrate it with your network settings, probably in [`/etc/network/interfaces*`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html#IFACE_OPTIONS) with liberal use of `up` and/or `pre-up` options (with `|| :` appended to avoid errors when testing). Be careful or you might lose remote access...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled Interfaces

```
ip link set dev eth0 up
ip link set dev wlan0 up
```

Comment: both interfaces are up and running. as i said: traceroute via wlan0 and eth0 are both working

Comment: did you saw a small yet distinct difference - why your wireless is going to different gate? I doubt that's direct problem-  but it might be lead to something underneath.